# Избежать дублирование кода Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

У меня есть метод getImage в котором я проверяю существование пути к изображению и если его нет, то возвращается путь к картинке-заглушке.

Проблема в том, что эта проверка существования пути к изображению нужна мне во многих моих моделях и думаю, что дублировать код метода будет плохой практикой. Как посоветуете решить эту проблему?

Comment: Вынесите метод в сервис или в базовую модель

Comment: Очень просто вынеси все в трейт и просто используй один раз написанный код. Но в целом тебе уже ответили, продумывай архитектуру. И как только начнешь понимать как и куда убирать код чтобы он не повторялся, дублирование уйдет.

Comment: @АндрейМелентьев Спасибо. Погуглил про трейты и узнал, что они как раз используются для избежание повторного использования кода

Comment: @Pahomka не слушайте глупости, не нужно для такого рода вещей трейты использовать

Comment: @InDevX Если не сложно, то объясните почему? Вот про трейты laravel нашел в гугле: Трейты предназначены для повторного использования кода и используются в различных классах и моделях. Трейты могут содержать методы, свойства и константы, и используются для добавления дополнительного функционала к классам.

Comment: @Pahomka скажем так, трейты не для тех кто спрашивает как убирать дублирование кода. В целом от пары трейтов особой беды не будет, но проблема приходит тогда когда они используются массово и в закладывают бизнес-логику. Если стоит вопрос использовать трейт или нет - не используйте, а с опытом и вопрос не актуальным станет

Comment: если у вас есть функционал, который многократно используется в разных моделях, то напрашивается отдельный класс-посредник для такого функционала, логично?

Comment: @Дмитрий Весь функционал = одному методу. Не логично же создавать отдельный класс ради одного метода. Просто я уже запутался, то трейты, то сервисы, то базовые классы, то новые классы

Comment: Видите ли.... Вы написали, что данный функционал вам нужен для многих моделей. Запихивать такое в абстрактный класс для всех моделей - такое себе (на самом деле просто не стоит. Потом еще что-то понадобиться, или каким-то моделям это не нужно и т.п.). Трейты конечно полезная конструкция, но @InDevX прав в том, что это инструмент, требующий большего погружения. В смысле SOLID я не вижу противоречия в том, чтобы функционал, нужный множеству моделей, как побочный, вынести в класс-посредник.